# Replace all backslashes in String

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to replace all `\` with `%5C` but getting wrong output:

```
String str="a\b";
str=str.replaceAll("\\\\", "%5C");
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: I need output like a%5Cb but i am getting like a and some unknown character next to that

Answer (score 8):

The variable `str` does not contain a backslash.  You somehow correctly escaped the backslashes in the `replaceAll()` args, but not in the original assignment to `str`.

```
String str="a\b";
```

should become:

```
String str="a\\b";
```

Answer (score 3):

`replaceAll` returns the result, so you should try to assign the results to your variable:

```
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String str="a\b";
        str = str.replaceAll("\\\\", "%5C");
        System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: sorry i posted it by mistake then too its not worked.. i corrected it.. please see above

Comment: This is a useful point to make, but the correct answer is from dashrb.

Comment: @duncan it contains a\b backslash

Comment: @theomega by mistake i posted it.. but the code i edited is absolutely right